# SSAS Calculation Format_string when zero

Tags: sql-server, ssas, zero, calculation, format-string

I have a following calculation:

```
SCOPE ({[Measures].[Fact Daily],[Measures].[Fact Last]});
    FORMAT_STRING(THIS) = IIF([Indicators].[Is Percent].&[1],'0.0%','#,0.0')
END SCOPE;
```

It worked fine, but now I have some values equal to zero (=0) in my fact table. This is real 0, not NULL or empty or something else.
So, the problem: the condition in IIF returns false anyway if [Measures].[Fact Daily] = 0.

How can I format 0 values?

Answer (score 0):

To format 0 values, I have to change IIF condition.
The solution was:

```
SCOPE ({[Measures].[Fact Daily],[Measures].[Fact Last]});
    FORMAT_STRING(THIS) = IIF(
        [Indicators].[Is Percent].CURRENTMEMBER = [Indicators].[Is Percent].&[1]
        ,'0.0%'
        ,'#,0.0')
END SCOPE;
```

**UPDATE:** But it does the following:

if [Measures].[Fact Daily] value <> 0 and [Indicators].[Is Percent].&[1] then format as *percent*

if [Measures].[Fact Daily] value <> 0 and [Indicators].[Is Percent].&[0] then format as *number*

**if [Measures].[Fact Daily] value = 0 and no matter which [Indicators].[Is Percent] selected, it formates as *percent*!!!**

So I continue to investigate the problem